# Asked to review someone else's edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edit

I appreciate the compliment, apparently someone asked me to review someone else's edits.

I wasn't the original poster of the message, nor the editor of the original post, nor a commenter or answerer on the post.

How did i get selected to review edits, and why?  what are the expectations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Main point can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing ("Who makes sure that proposed edits are good?" section)

  > Any user can propose edits, but not all edits are publicly visible immediately. **If a user has less than 2,000 reputation, the suggested edit is placed in a review queue. Two (three on Stack Overflow) accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it. Users with more than 2,000 reputation are considered trusted community members and can edit posts without going through the review process.**
- [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta) has a bit more details on this:

  > **Suggested Edits:** This task targets posts edited by users who have not yet earned the reputation to fully edit. Your job is to read these edits and:
  >
  > decide to Approve the edit as is
  >   Reject the edit
  >   Edit the original post and make your own edit
  >   Delete the post (moderator only)
  >   or skip it if you are Not Sure.
  >
  > The minimum reputation to perform this task corresponds with the ability to edit any post (currently 2,000).
- The overall workflow is covered here in detail, including guidelines and expectations: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
- And overall review queue coverage here: [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: thank you! i missed the FAQ somehow

Answer (score 3):

Everyone with the Edit Posts privilege, at 2k rep, can review suggested edits.